# iOS UITests - Detect if any XCUIElement have ever been tapped on current run

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xcode-ui-testing

While working on iOS, UITest, how can i detect if specific XCUIElement has already been tapped or not?

For example,

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let button1 = app.tabBars.buttons["Home"]
button1.tap()
let button2 = app.tabBars.buttons["Home"].tap()
button2.tap() // Here, I want to detect button2 as already tapped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XCUIElement.isEnabled`, `XCUIElement.isSelected` and `XCUIElement.value` can give you state information about the element.

If you expect the button to be toggled on/off, use the enabled or selected state on UIControl (UIButton inherits from UIControl) to set those properties and access them from your tests via XCUIElement.

If you want the button to count how many times it has been tapped, increment the value in your app each time it is tapped and access the `value` property in your test.

Answer (score 1):

You will **have** to do this in the application's code and not in the UI Test target (from a UI Test).

There are many ways you could achieve this but one way would be to just disable buttons after they have been tapped once. Would probably be a good idea to wrap this application logic in `#if DEBUG` clauses if you want this functionality around permanently for tests. Additionally I'd recommend toggling this logic on/off from UI Tests via launch argument which **can** be set from UI tests.